# Struts program does not show properties value

Tags: struts2

i am try a program of Struts to show french value...for this i have define properties in message.properties file and in message_fr.properties files.  but at run time when i access value of property it show blank space.
i have include struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar, struts2-json-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar on classpath.

for example define in properties file:
`pro.color=Blue`

on jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/user" prefix="user" %>


<s:property value="pro.color"/>
```

now it show blank space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<s:property value="%{getText('pro.color')}"/>
```